# Prove that g(0)=0?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, integration

(taken from Spivak's calculus page 281)

> Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are differentiable functions satisfying
>   $$ \int_{0}^{f(x)} (fg)(t) \, \mathrm{d}t=g(f(x))$$
>   Prove that $g(0)=0$.

Now if $f(x)=0$ in some point then it's straightforward that $g(f(x))=g(0)=0$.

Anyways:
differentiating the first formula we get the following equation :

$$f'(x).(fg)(f(x))=g'(f(x)).f'(x).$$

Let's suppose that $f'(x)=0$, thus $f$ is constant i.e $f(x)=c$, if $c=0$ we are done, $g(0)=0$ , if $c\neq 0$ then :

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{c} fg(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$=g(c)

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{c} g(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$=g(c)/c, **i'm stuck here** , how can we prove that g(0)=0 (or get a contradiction) from this equation?
EDIT : i had a lot of typos fixed them , sorry first time posting..
EDIT 2 : i checked spivak's calculus solutions book and i didn't find this question he just jumos from question 7 to 9 (ignoring this one )

Comment: By $fg(t)$ do you mean $f(g(t))$ or $f(t)g(t)$? I am assuming it means $f(g(t))$. Please correct if my assumption is wrong.

Comment: fg(t) means f(t)g(t) , sorry

Comment: Thanks Larson for pointing out. Please edit the question to make this clear for everyone.

Comment: If $f(x) = 0$, then $\int_0^0 f(t)g(t) dt = 0$. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

I'll show that $g(0) = 0$ does not have to hold.

We have
$$
\displaystyle c \int_{0}^{c} g(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = g(c)
$$
Now take $g(x) = e^x$ and we will find such a $c$ that above identity holds.
$$
c\int_0^c e^t dt = g(c)
$$
$$
c ( e^c - 1  ) = e^c
$$
$$
0 = (1-c)e^c + c
$$
And as you can see from its [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281-x%29e%5Ex%20%2b%20x) it has nonzero solution. So for $f(x) = c \approx 1.34998$  and $g(x) = e^x$ the property 
$$
\displaystyle \int_{0}^{f(x)} f(t)g(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = g(f(x))
$$
holds and $g(0)\neq 0 $. It would be interesting to investigate a little variation to you quastion.

> Decide if there is nontrivial $g$ that for every $f$
>   $$
> \displaystyle \int_{0}^{f(x)} f(t)g(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = g(f(x))
> $$
>   holds. And decide if this nontrivial $g$ has to also satisfy $g(0)=0$

Comment: But... but...... Spivak can't be wrong!

Comment: You like proofs by authority? :D

Comment: Well I don't have Spivak so I can't check that OP rewrote the question right. Or I'm wrong but I can't see where.

Comment: Question is correctly posted by OP and it is problem no 8 from page 281 of Spivak.

Comment: the chapter that discusses logarithmic functions is after this chapter , maybe spivak just ignored this one

Comment: I just looked up the answer book and it would seem that Spivak himself didn't even have a solution to this problem. Apparently he skipped it without realizing it. His solution for question 8 became the solution for question 9. Maybe his 4th edition has the problem removed?

Answer (score 1):

We have to understand that by the conditions given it follows that 
$$f'(x)f(f(x))g(f(x)) = g'(f(x))f'(x)$$ and cancelling $f'(x)$ we can see that $$f(y)g(y) = g'(y)$$ and therefore $g$ is anti-derivative of $fg$. It now follows clearly that the integral in question must be $g(f(x)) - g(0)$ and since it is given as $g(f(x))$ it follows that $g(0) = 0$.

Comment: Why can you cancel $f'(x)$? What if $f'(x)=0$ on an interval?

Comment: To N.S.: I think there should be added assumption of $f'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$. I have not been able to conclude $g(0) = 0$ without this assumption and hence the solution presented above is incomplete. I am working on doing away with this assumption.

Comment: ^this the whole question discuss the fact that i chose f'(x)=0

Comment: Also I think that apart from considering $f'(x) = 0$ identically we must also consider the case when $f'(x) = 0$ for infinitely many values of $x$. On the other hand I think we can also try to follow your initial approach that 1) either $f(x) = 0$ for some $x$ or $f(x)$ is of same sign everywhere. Just considering the case when $f(x)$ is constant does not seem to be the whole story.

Comment: If we look at the first answer from Tom where he shows a counter example for the case of constant function $f$, it is clear that the result fails if we don't assume $f'(x) \neq 0$. So it seems there must have been certain conditions on $f'(x)$ which Spivak has not mentioned in the problem.

Comment: [in answer to Paramanand Singh - for some reason the comment button wouldn't work] Unconvinced. Suppose the range of f is [c, infinity), c > 0. Then the deduction f(y)g(y)=g′(y) is only valid for y >= c.

Comment: You need more reputation before you can comment. Regards

Comment: haruspex, please see my comments in my answer and also the first answer from "tom". The question needs additional hypotheses otherwise it is wrong.